# Lagrange method, find polynomial with Python

Tags: numerical-methods, python, lagrange-interpolation

I have to find the Langrange polynomium for exp(-x)*cos(4*pi*x) for
 x in(0,3). I have found a python code to plot these approximation as a graph, but how can I use these to find the approximated Langrange polynomium in the interval x in(0,3)?
Here is the code:

> [image]

Comment: There is no Lagrange polynomial for a function. There is a Lagrange polynomial for a collection of points.

Comment: You could at least cite the [source](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3412386/115115) of your code. And since its invention by Fibonacci, it is "binomial" (=sum of two terms) and since the invention of the word by Viete, it is "polynomial" (sum of many terms).

Answer (score 1):

I think you can just extract the coefficients of the polynomial. This is from https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.lagrange.html

```
Interpolate f(x) = x^3  
by 3 points.
>>>

>>> from scipy.interpolate import lagrange
>>> x = np.array([0, 1, 2])
>>> y = x**3
>>> poly = lagrange(x, y)

Since there are only 3 points, Lagrange polynomial has degree 2. Explicitly, it is given by
>>>

>>> from numpy.polynomial.polynomial import Polynomial
>>> Polynomial(poly).coef
array([ 3., -2.,  0.])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to know the coefficients of the polynomial, you can simply `print` it, e.g.

```
from scipy.interpolate import lagrange
from numpy import exp, cos, linspace, pi
f = (lambda x: exp(-x) * cos(4 * pi * x))
x = linspace(0, 3, 5)
print(lagrange(x, f(x)))
```

[will give](https://repl.it/repls/SleepyDescriptiveMenus)

```
        4         3         2
0.6189 x - 4.046 x + 8.594 x - 6.394 x + 1
```

Comment: This is fine if you just want to _see_ the coefficients. If you want to use them for further computation you need them in python, not in the output stream.

Comment: @EthanBolker, you nailed it.

Comment: @EthanBolker. Nice, thank you. But how do I use the coefficients to find the Langrange polynomium?

Comment: @user66081. Nice, thank you. But how do I use the coefficients to find the Langrange polynomium?

Comment: @math: the Lagrange polynomial in this case is $p_4(x) = 0.6189 x^4 - 4.046 x^3 + 8.594 x^2 - 6.394 x + 1$, up to rounding.